# it shows when I start expo project, so how can I fix this?

Tags: react-native

[Reanimated] Mismatch between JavaScript part and native part of Reanimated (3.0.2 vs. 2.14.4). Did you forget to re-build the app after upgrading react-native-reanimated? If you use Expo Go, you must downgrade to 2.14.4 which is bundled into Expo SDK.

ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined, js engine: hermes

ERROR  Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:

* Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.

* A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called., js engine: hermes

Comment: Please include information like the Expo SDK version, whether you're using a custom development client, and whether iOS or Android.

Answer (score 8):

Firstly;
run npm install react-native-reanimated@2.14.4

After;
start with expo start -c

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue, resolved by adding resolution to package.json, which decides which version of the package should be used when this kind of conflicts occure.

```
  "resolutions": {
    "react-native-reanimated": "3.3.0"
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

I've tried a lot too. This solution worked for me.

1. Delete node_modules folder
2. Run "npm install react-native-reanimated@3.3.0"
3. Dependency version not starting with tilde(~) or caret(^) [see also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22343224/whats-the-difference-between-tilde-and-caret-in-package-json)

   "dependencies": {
   ...
   "react-native-reanimated": "3.3.0"
   ...
   }
4. Run npm install
5. Run npx expo start --reset-cache

Answer (score 1):

if u are using expo, there might be facing this kind of version issues due to differences between react native cli.
The solution that u can try is to change your dependencies version of react native reanimated in package json to "react-native-reanimated": "^2.14.4",
and run npm install.
Last try to run command: expo start -c to reset the cache in your app and it will works perfectly fine!

Comment: "react-native-reanimated": "^2.14.4" will install version 2.17.0 as of today and it does not work.  You must use "react-native-reanimated": "2.14.4" instead.